# Post HTTP request from qt5 using qml

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

Hi everyone, 
           I am trying to send the http post request from my qt app. I have read alot and still struggling to get some concepts of signals and slots. Would be nice if somebody can help me out from here..

here is my qml code snippet:

```
TextField { id: u_name; placeholderText: userText(); Layout.fillWidth: true; style: StyleTextField {} }
                TextField { id: p_text;   echoMode: TextInput.Password;  Layout.fillWidth: true; style: StyleTextField {} }
                Button {
                    id: signInButton
                    text: "Sign In";
                    style: StyleButton {}
                    Layout.fillWidth: true;
                    //Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignTop;
                    signal esLoginClicked()
                    onClicked: {
                        if (u_name.text.length)  Settings.userText =  u_name.text;
                        if (p_text.text.length)  Settings.passText  = p_text.text;
                      signInButton.esLoginClicked().connect(esLogin(u_name.text,       p_text.text));
                        page_stack.pop();
                    }
                }
```

Here I am trying to get username and password from user and want to pass it to slot "esLogin" that I have declared in my header file using signal esLoginCLicked() which I have created here only.  My header files looks like this...

```
Q_OBJECT
Q_PROPERTY(QString userText  READ userText  WRITE setUserText NOTIFY userTextChanged)
Q_PROPERTY(QString passText  READ passText  WRITE setPassText NOTIFY passTextChanged)

 public:
 static esQuickSettings *instance(void);

 public:
 QString userText(void);
 QString passText(void);
// void esLoginClicked(void);
// void esLoginClicked(const QString& userText, const QString passText);

 public:
 void setUserText(const QString& user);
 void setPassText(const QString& passt);
 void esLogin(const QString& userText, const QString& passText);
  signals:
 void userTextChanged(void);
 void passTextChanged(void);
```

but somehow I am not able to make it work and missing some key concept here to make signal and slot work.

P.S: I want to take input from QML and put in slot which will have the definition in cpp file respective to header.

Comment: "but somehow I am not able to make it work" -> what error exactly are you facing? Btw, can you fix the formatting? What are u_name and p_text?

Comment: it is saying...TypeError: Property 'esLogin' of object esQuickSettings(0x2a046a0) is not a function..

Comment: I know why this is error as esLogin is not property I have defined in header file...I have defined it as Slot....but with slot I do not know how to connect this slot with signal I created in qml

Comment: Can you not use the regular `QObject::connect(object, SIGNAL(esLoginClicked(const QString&, const QString&)), &foo, SLOT(esLogin(const QString&, const QString&)));`?

Comment: just want to understand...I will declare this connection in my header file and defined the esLogin() method in my cpp file, but the data from my QML will pass to this method..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are (at least) two ways to address this issue, but I will only let you know one of them based on the comment discussion.

Connect the QML signal to the C++ slot.

#### main.qml

```
...
Button {
    id: signInButton
    // This is necessary for finding this nested item in C++
    objectName: "SignInButtonObjectName"
    ...
}
...
```

#### main.cpp

```
...
QQmlEngine engine;
QQmlComponent component(&engine, "main.qml");
QObject *object = component.create();
QObject *childObject = object->findChild<QObject*>("SignInButtonObjectName");
Foo foo;
QObject::connect(childObject, SIGNAL(esLoginClicked(const QString&, const QString&)), &foo, SLOT(esLogin(const QString&, const QString&)));
...
```

The other approach would be to call the C++ slot in your qml code when the signal happens to be emitted which is probably even simpler. In that case, you would make the method below either `Q_INVOKABLE` or even better: a slot.

```
void esLogin(const QString& userText, const QString& passText);
```

Then, you would need to make sure that this method is exposed to qml via context properties, namely: you would make the class a context property which would be available to qml for calling like foo.esLogin() in your desired qml signal handler.

Comment: Thanks for the explained answer, I managed to understood both the approaches but getting connect fails error(null) but I hope I could resolve it ..if not will ask..thanks...

Comment: Hi, Laszlo, when I am exposing declared slot in QML using setContextProperty, it is throwing this error "redefinition of 'struct qmetatypeid", and now It seems like to give the same error with the approach you explained above...any idea what I am missing...seems like some linking error\

Comment: How exactly do you expose the context property?

Comment: QDeclarativeView view;
NetworkInfo myClass;
view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myObject", &myClass);  view.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("qml/esQuick/esQuickPageLogin.qml"));
Now accessing my slot using myObject

Comment: Hi Laszlo, any idea...this error is troubling alot ..tried everything but throwing same error in all the cases...

Comment: @Jeet: I am now away from keyboard, visiting family and friends. I will be back tomorrow morning the latest to help with this. Apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: No problem, thanks for reply and please take your time ..dont worry...have nice one

Comment: @Jeet: re, is NetworkInfo inheriting QObject? Can you paste your code on pastebin.kde.org and gimme the link?

Comment: @Jeet: 404: Page not found – the page http://goo.gl/t44IhF%22 does not exist. I think you meant http://pastebin.kde.org/pd4ikf3wr. Do not use quotes for urls. ;) Swap 36 and 38.

Comment: @Jeet: yes, a serious one. I even mentioned.

Comment: where did you mention...on pastebin.kde.org link or the one comment about swapping above

Comment: You are trying to set a context property on a source not yet specified. How did you think it could work? :)

Comment: aha, I just swapped those lines which means now it is specifying source from qml and then applying context property ...but still same error...

Comment: I do not think you have ever pasted the full output. Also, I would try without calling fromLocalFile()... Anyway, we have run way off-topic. The approaches are good. You are having some implementation details issue. I am afraid, I do not have more time for this now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44214/discussion-between-jeet-and-laszlo-papp)

Comment: I am afraid you would need to be providing a self-contained example. Currently, I could not reproduce your issue. I have several applications out there working on this design principle. :)

Comment: @ Laszlo: After spending some more time, I solved that problem and managed to established connection. It was kinda bug in qt ..dont remember much about how to regenerate that bug...Thanks for your time and help....this might be useful for u...https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/27198

Comment: @Jeet: great, thanks. I was not aware of this, so you have just made me learn something new. :) So, you were using OSX?

Comment: my Pleasure, sorry for troubling you before, I am kinda noob in qt, so do not have much idea about it.. no I am using Fedora..